# Concatenate two list items into one item

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to concatenate list items based on the **productId**. Apologies for the JSON naming, I know it's not the best, I'm not in control of this.

If items in my list have the same productId, I would like to concatenate them and create one item with a **fees** array containing the variable properties i.e. **costType**, **feeId**, **feeName** etc (see Desired result). When the productId is the same, the branchName, branchId, productName and bundle will all have the same value.

```
[{
        "branchname": "Branch",
        "branchid": "b7d79617-1c36-4be1-87b7-d7a910a5b72e",
        "productid": "d029d731-92a6-4bd3-b020-1ad282af8308",
        "productname": "Local Search",
        "bundle": false,
        "costtype": "Cost",
        "feeid": "c3d5fb93-f8be-4be2-b5b8-dd1701614e05",
        "feename": "Fee",
        "discounttype": null,
        "discountamount": null,
        "baseprice": 20,
        "grossprice": 20,
        "vatrate": 20,
        "vatamount": 4,
        "netprice": 24
    }, {
        "branchname": "Branch",
        "branchid": "b7d79617-1c36-4be1-87b7-d7a910a5b72e",
        "productid": "d029d731-92a6-4bd3-b020-1ad282af8308",
        "productname": "Local Search",
        "bundle": false,
        "costtype": "Sale",
        "feeid": "7299a1fe-fe3d-43e2-b21a-3710e1bcd720",
        "feename": "Standard Product Fee",
        "discounttype": null,
        "discountamount": null,
        "baseprice": 60,
        "grossprice": 60,
        "vatrate": 20,
        "vatamount": 12,
        "netprice": 72
    }
]
```

Desired result:

```
[{
        "branchname": "Branch",
        "branchid": "b7d79617-1c36-4be1-87b7-d7a910a5b72e",
        "productid": "d029d731-92a6-4bd3-b020-1ad282af8308",
        "productname": "Local Search",
        "bundle": false,
        "fees": [{
                "costtype": "Cost",
                "feeid": "c3d5fb93-f8be-4be2-b5b8-dd1701614e05",
                "feename": "Fee",
                "discounttype": null,
                "discountamount": null,
                "baseprice": 20,
                "grossprice": 20,
                "vatrate": 20,
                "vatamount": 4,
                "netprice": 24
            }, {
                "costtype": "Sale",
                "feeid": "7299a1fe-fe3d-43e2-b21a-3710e1bcd720",
                "feename": "Standard Product Fee",
                "discounttype": null,
                "discountamount": null,
                "baseprice": 60,
                "grossprice": 60,
                "vatrate": 20,
                "vatamount": 12,
                "netprice": 72
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried grouping by productId i.e. `list.GroupBy(g => g.ProductId)` but I'm not sure what to do next. I'm looking for an elegant LINQ solution if possible.

Comment: Is it just the product id you want to group on? What about the other 4 fields which are alongside that apart from the fees?

Comment: @TanveerBadar does it matter? They will be the same if the productId is the same.

Comment: @Chris That was the question - it's not defined that `branch` or `bundle` will be the same for any product id. It would be easy to imagine that one product could belong to more than one branch, or vice-versa, since we don't know exactly what this is describing.

Comment: With all these limitations and data variations, its better to break down the collection data and populate in the related types separately.

Comment: @RufusL branch and bundle will always be the same. The JSON is result of a query whereby it has been filtered by a branchId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your list into the new format with this query:

```
var condensed = 
    list.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
        .Select(g => 
        {
            var first = g.First();
            return new
            {
                first.BranchName,
                first.BranchId,
                first.ProductId,
                first.ProductName,
                first.Bundle,
                fees = g.Select(p => new
                {
                    p.CostType,
                    p.FeeId,
                    p.FeeName,
                    p.DiscountType,
                    p.DiscountAmount,
                    p.BasePrice,
                    p.GrossPrice,
                    p.VatRate,
                    p.VatAmount,
                    p.NetPrice
                })
                .ToList()
            };
        })
        .ToList();
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tweKHY

Comment: Thanks Brian - exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

To generate output similar to what you want - and making a couple of assumptions along the way - try something like this:

```
list.GroupBy(item => item.ProductId /*, <your value selector lambda goes here which only returns a tuple composed of what goes as children of "fee" element> */).Select(g => 
{
    var item = g.First();
    return new { item.BranchName, item.BranchId, item.ProductId, item.ProductName, item.Bundle };
});
```

Comment: `/*, <your value selector lambda goes here which only returns a tuple composed of what goes as children of "fee" element> */` Could you please explain this more?